# JMeter, подключение сторонних Test plan

Tags: test-automation, jmeter, реализация

Формулировка заголовка возможно не точна.
Вводная: в JMeter реализовано функциональное тестирование, состоящие в основном из HTTP и JDBC запросов. Разная функциональность оформлена в разные Test Plan.
  Но есть подготовительный этап, который одинаковый для всех функциональных тестов. Операции в подготовительном этапе меняются.
Проблема: автоматически держать подготовительный этап в актуальном состоянии для функционального тестирования.

Как лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от того, что вы называете Test Plan и насколько они автономны это может быть:

- [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)
- [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)

Но вообще хорошим тоном считается выносить функционал, который может быть переиспользован в текущем либо внешних скриптах в [Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments)

Comment: Как-то не уловил сразу Include Controller и Test Fragment, но теперь вроде все проясняется. Спасибо.